# How to Get Order Details per a single User in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, eloquent, e-commerce

I am making a multi-vendor ecommerce website using Laravel 7. I am trying to make an Order History page where in a single can user can view only his/her own orders. I am having a problem building the query on my OrderHistoryController. These are the codes on my controller:

```
 $users = User::get();
    $orders = Order::find($users);

    return view('order-history', compact('orders'));
```

And I'm trying to loop $orders on my blade file. I have:

```
 @foreach ($orders as $order)
     <div>{{ $order->id}}</div>
     <div>{{ $order->grand_total}}</div>
 @endforeach
```

I am trying to pass the order id and order grand total to my view. I don't get any error however it shows a different order details from a different customer. How do I do this?

Comment: how is `Order` related to `User` ... a `user_id` field? Did you setup any relationship on the Models?

Comment: Yes, I user a user_id field to relate my users table to orders table. I have setup a relationship on my 'Order' model and 'User' model too. I was able to connect  both but instead of showing the specific orders for a specific user, i'm getting a different order showing from a different user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use MySQL (or any other database you are using) table relationships and foreign keys.

So, your orders table, should have columns `id`, `user_id`, `date`, and so on. The important thing is `user_id` column. You want to make that column a [foreign key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). That basically means that `user_id` will hold an `id` value from another table, in this case user. See how to make foreign key columns in laravel migrations [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations).

Next up is to use Laravel's built in model relationships. You can read more about them [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships). Basically, in your orders model you want to have a function `user` which returns `$this->belongsTo(App\Models\User::class)` and in your user model you want to have a function `orders` which returns `$this->hasMany(App\Models\Order::class)` (or whatever the namespace is for both of them).

That way, you can call `$user->orders` and get a collection of `Order` models which will contain only the orders of that particular user.

**Definitely read the documentation carefully and learn basic concepts of the framework first and how relational databases function!**
You can get a lot of this information just by googling it or reading the documentation of Laravel or any other framework you plan on using! Good luck learning :)

Comment: That worked for me! Thank you very much for your help. I got confused with the relationships because I was able to relate it at first but it's showing all the orders. Now I was able to show only the orders of any specific users. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Jemy please mark the answer as correct so other users can now this issue is resolved. Thank you